# WPF - Select File Path at Design Time

Tags: c#, wpf, design-time

So I'm trying to implement some design time functionality to a control of mine and I'm having an issue. I want the end  user to be able to use an open file dialog to select an image externally, so that the property stores the path to that image.

Whenever I use Image or ImageBrush types for the property, it tries to add the image as an embedded resource.

So my question really is...

Are there any types that I can expose as a property that will prompt with a file dialog at design time to populate the field, or is there any type of attribute I can apply to the property to make it do this.

**Things I've Tried:**

1. Custom UITypeEditor
2. URI Type
3. FileInfo Type

Comment: I think for this you would need to write a Visual Studio addin.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to avoid that. I'm surprised that this functionality didn't carry over from WinForms to WPF.